# Paginate text file in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to display log file in browser, and that file could be big enough. So, I need to divide it, for example 100 lines per page.

Method looks like that for now:

```
public function show($request)
{
    $file = File::get(storage_path("logs/$request.log"));
    return view('backend.log', compact('file'));
}
```

How to add `paginate(100)` and how to display it in blade file? It doesn't work without Eloquent, but I don't need database.

Comment: I think you can use tail command and read 100 lines, after return this response for the browser.

Comment: @gaidyjg you mean package `spatie/laravel-tail`?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Although I meant to the command used in linux terminal

Comment: I'm afraid the Laravel default paginator comes only with support for Eloquent data by default, you may need to write your own class for this, or perhaps use a package.

Comment: @gaidyjg as a win10 user, I cannot do this. Anyway, I think, it's better to do it using php, not external commands.

Comment: @WiGeeky thanks. If you want to suggest package or code for file pagination, you can create answer and I'll accept it. If not, thanks anyway.